# ion-content directive scroll div doesn't display data

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following very simple html in my ionic app

```
<ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

The problem is that the `ion-content` directive wraps the `ion-nav-view` content with this html

```
<div class="scroll" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"></div>
```

It seems that if I remove the `translate3d` attribute the content is displayed, but I have to assume there is a better way, or something that I'm missing.

The content displayed by my template is very simple

```
<div>
    <p>Welcome to the main screen</p>
</div>
```

Here's a plunk of the problem I'm experiencing

http://plnkr.co/edit/QdekKA5fXIqn2tgi3Etp?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I find when I update your index.html to following it loads the tabs.html.

```
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

And I have moved nav bar to tabs.html to show nav bar on all pages.

```
<ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

<!-- Pets Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Works" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- About Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Broken" icon="icon ion-gear-b" href="#/tab/account">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

I think what is happening is that ui-router loads abstract rout html first and then goes to default route because no route is specified.

```
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "tabs.html"
})
```

This is where you specified default route.

```
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
```